# How to convert a django model field to different dimension on save?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to convert dollars to cents on save for the Django model.

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    backup = False
    ...
    device_type = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='device type')
    transaction_sum = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='sum in dollars') # this field
```

How can I do it by using the Django Model environment to save it in cents?

UPD: the question is more about getters and setters. Analogy:

[image]

I need the same conversion on the fly here.

Comment: You're unlikely to get many answers without showing your model code or any effort.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `save` method in your model:

```
class Money (models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # enter code here...
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```